# Start/stop a jquery function depending on the windows width

Tags: jquery, function, resize, width

I have a jquery function, named setSlider.
I want that this function don't run on screen < 1200px.

I managed to test the screen size, and launch or not the function with

```
if($(window).width() < 1200){ return false; }
```

For example, if you have a windows width of 1300px, the function runs.
If you have a screen width of 900px, the function doesn't launch. Great !

But I have a problem when you resize.
If you resize from 1300 to 900, the function continuing to operate the action..
And if you start from 900px to 1200px, the function does not start.

I have try that :

```
 $(window).on('resize', function(e) { setSlider(); });
```

But it seems it does'n work...
Thank you if you have an idea !

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused when you want the function to run but the below will run the setSlider function when the window width is greater than or equal to 1200px

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   if($(window).width() > 1200){
      setSlider();
   }
});
```

The above will run the function when the browser window is resized as is great than 1200px. If you want to do the same when the page is first opened then you can either do something like:

```
$(function(){
   if($(window).width() > 1200){
      setSlider();
   }
});
```

or you can call the window resize function when the page loads like.

```
$(function(){
   $(window).resize();
});
```

Comment: it's already jQuery and you have a typo on the function's name `setSlider();`

Comment: @JonathandeM. Thank you and I meant to say the dedicated resize function... not that it acts differently from on.'resize'.

Comment: @Damien I'm confused when you want the function to run?

Comment: Thanks ! I want that the function run when windows width is bigger than 1200px. If you resize, the function stop. And if you start with a little screen, the function starts on resize when your windows is >= 1200px